# Limit size of static file served in Nginx

Tags: nginx

I have a storage server providing downloading services in an intranet. Recently I've added a reverse proxy on a gateway so the download services are accessible from the internet. However because bandwidth costs and paired with other reasons, I would like to restrict the maximum file size for a single request, say one MiB.

I have currently two ideas

1. Configure Nginx on the origin server to deny access to files exceeding the threshold
2. Configure Nginx on the gateway to respond with some 4xx code once the proxy backend responds with a big value in `Content-Length` header.

I still haven't Googled out how to do either (any one of the ideas suffices).

In case it helps: The origin server runs stock Nginx from Debian APT repository, while the gateway runs OpenResty (Nginx with LUA). I however am not familiar with LUA.